# How to return only new items in real time when they are posted by another endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to do live streaming example app, where I can live update the list in the browser. I want to return all elements and then still listening (don't stop the stream) when new item is add to the database. Then I want to show new item in the browser. My current solution all the time prints all items (second by second) but I think there is better solution, when I can a) find the difference in list from last processing repository.findAll() and return only currList - prevList b) I can listen to some kind of events? Like inserting to table and add new item to still opened stream.

Here is my current code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/songs")
public class SongController {

    private final SongRepository songRepository;

    public SongController(SongRepository songRepository) {
        this.songRepository = songRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Song> getAllSongs() {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .flatMap(x -> songRepository.findAll());
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<Song> addSong(@RequestBody Song song) {
        return songRepository.save(song);
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks like now:

[image]

As you can see, Its obviously looped, and I just need plain list with 7 elements on begining and then +1 element every time I post new song (by addSong()).

I don't need a entire ready solution, I just don't know what should I use.

Thank you in advance, cheers

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there are three options that have different pros and cons.

1. You could create a web socket connection from the browser to your backend service. This will create a bi-directional connection that will allow you push updates from the server to your browser. In this instance whenever you add a song you would then write that song to the web socket connection and handle that on the browser side, so adding it to the list in the browser.

The cons of this are in my experience web socket connections are finicky and aren't the most stable or reliable.

2. You could use server side events. I haven't used this personally but I have heard this can be a viable options for pushing events from the server to the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events
3. You could poll the endpoint. I know this approach gets a lot of hate in recent years but it is a viable options. The benefit with polling the endpoint is that it is resilient to failures. If your backend is overloaded and can't respond for one request it will likely be able to respond to a subsequent request. Also there are ways of improving commonly used endpoints so you're not hammering your database like a cache or something of that nature.

Comment: USSE seems to be the best of this three.